# How do powerups and pickups stack up in Temple Run 2?

Tags: temple-run-2

How does the duration of the powerups and pickups stack up? Does it make a difference if I activate my powerup (e.g. Coin Magnet) first and then collect one or vice versa?

What's the most efficient way to use the powerup ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not stack.

It is most efficient to use one when you are not about to collect one, or have recently collected one, that is the same type. Combining different types of powerups can be useful, though; if you activate your magnet just before (or after) collecting a boost, you will quickly cover more distance - because of the boost - while collecting all of the coins in range along the way (because of the magnet).

If you have everything upgraded completely (duration of powerups, frequency of powerup spawns), then each powerup you collect will last most of the way to the next spawn. Potentially the least efficient time to use a powerup is just after one you collected expires, since it may be "wasted" by picking up the next powerup (no point activating your magnet if you can just pick one up). Activating a boost at this point may also make it very difficult to collect the next powerup, since you'll be moving much faster when it appears.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What's about collecting one after the double tap activation? I managed to extend the duration of the effect. Can it be that just the timer is set back?

Comment: Yes, the one you activated will expire normally, but the one you picked up will be active for the normal length of time (starting from when you collect it).

Comment: I‘ll wait a few days for other answers with accepting.